# Call C# from Javascript in ios UIWebview

Tags: javascript, web

I have a web app and my backend is implemented in `C#`.

I would like to call the `CallMethod` (backend) from `HelloWorld` (frontend) function.

Ive tried the following code but i'm missing something...

**backend code:**

```
Class CallClass
{
    public void CallMethod(string x)
    {
     //I write me logic here.
    }
}
```

**frontend code:**

```
<script type=”text/JavaScript”>
    var x='123';
    function HelloWorld(){
        CallClass.CallMethod(x);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: that's invalid javascript syntax ([reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)). Does your server side implemented in C#?

Comment: How c# came into picture in ios UIWebView? can you explain little more?

Comment: @JossefHarush Yes my backend code is in C#

Comment: @null1941 I'm developing an iOS app, I'm calling JavaScript method on button click event from html page. In my javascript method I inturn need to  call my C# method where I can implement some logic from values passed by javascript method.

Comment: that c# method is present in your backend server?

Comment: Why you are directly calling Method Present in Backend? Expose REST API on your backend and send sned HTTP Request from your front end javascript.

Comment: @null1941 I need the log the error caught in Javascript

Comment: Did u understand my last comment exposing REST End point?

Comment: I'm not sure of using it. Can you post the solution. I'll try that  out.